# Fast elementwise apply function using index and column name - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which can be simplified like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['01/11/2017', '01/11/2017', '01/11/2017', '02/11/2017', '02/11/2017', '02/11/2017'],
                 columns = ['Period','_A', '_B', '_C'] )
df.Period = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
df
```

which looks like:

`Date    Period _A      _B       _C
01/11/2017  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
01/11/2017  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
01/11/2017  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
02/11/2017  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
02/11/2017  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
02/11/2017  3   NaN     NaN     NaN`

And I want to apply my function to each cell

`Get_Y(Date, Period, Location)`
(where `_A, _B, _C, ...` are the locations).

`Get_Y` is a complex function, that looks up data from other dataframes using the Date, Period and Location, and based on criteria gives a value for Y (a float between 0 and 1).

I have managed to make this work with iterrows:

```
for index, row in PeriodDF.iterrows():
    date = index
    Period = row.loc[row.index[0]]  
    LocationList = row.index[1:]
    print(date, Period)
    for Location in LocationList :
        PeriodDF.loc[(PeriodDF.index == date)&(PeriodDF.Period == Period), Location] = Get_Y(date, Period, Location)
```

But this takes over 1 hour.

There must be a way to do this faster in pandas.

I have tried creating 3 dataframes, one an array of the `Period`, one an array of the `Location`, and one of the `Date`, but not sure how to apply `Get_Y` elementwise, using the value from each dataframe.

Comment: it depends on what `Get_Y` does and is implemented, can you post that code

Comment: Updated that in the question.

Comment: Loops are usually efficient (unless you do **lots** of iterations). The culprit is probably `Get_Y`.

Comment: `Get_Y` is relatively fast, gets a solution in 200ms. But because the dataframe is of shape 35,000 x 15, the runtime is ~72 minutes.

Comment: 200ms is relatively slow if you want to calculate 35k lines.

Comment: 35000*200ms is 2 hours. you need probably to refactor your problem.

Comment: why not include, `Get_Y()`?